# how to use the below javascript as common, instead of writing in each div tag?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript goes here.. and i have many sections of div tag.. i want to make this script common for all divs that i am using.. where as only the url's have to change reference with the corresponding div.. plz help..??

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var feedcontainer1=document.getElementById("feeddiv1")
var rssoutput1="<b>TOI</b><br /><ul>"

function rssfeedsetup1(){
google.load("feeds", "1")
var feedpointer1=new google.feeds.Feed("http://handheld.softpedia.com/backend-software.xml") //Google Feed API method
feedpointer1.setNumEntries(10) //Google Feed API method
feedpointer1.load(displayfeed1) //Google Feed API method
}

function displayfeed1(result){
if (!result.error){
var thefeeds1=result.feed.entries
for (var i=0; i<thefeeds1.length; i++)
rssoutput1+="<li><a href='" + thefeeds1[i].link + "'>" + thefeeds1[i].title + " »" + "</a></li>"
rssoutput1+="</ul>"
feedcontainer1.innerHTML=rssoutput1
}
else
alert("Error fetching feeds!")
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a callback function that knows about where to put the data returned from google. In Javascript, the best way to do this is to use a function closure to remember the destination. Therefore, you need a function that creates the callback, such as:

```
// Return function that receives feed data from google and populates the given div.
function makeDisplayFeedCallback(divId) {
    var destDiv = document.getElementById(divId)
    return function callback(result) {
        var output = "<b>TOI</b><br /><ul>"
        if (!result.error) {
            var entries = result.feed.entries
            for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)
                output += "<li><a href='" + entries[i].link + "'>" + entries[i].title + " »" + "</a></li>"
            output += "</ul>"
            destDiv.innerHTML = output
        }
        else
            alert("Error fetching feeds!")
    }
}
```

This function can be called multiple times, and each time it will return a function that knows how to populate different divs. You'll call it something like:

```
var callback = makeDisplayFeedCallback("feeddiv1");
setupRssFeed(callback);
```

and finally, your setup function needs the callback (and perhaps other parameters):

```
function setupRssFeed(callback) {
    google.load("feeds", "1")
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://handheld.softpedia.com/backend-software.xml");
    feed.setNumEntries(10);
    feed.load(callback);
}
```

Overall, this is better separation of concerns as well, so it will be easier to maintain.

Comment: am getting those errors

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Feed' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: the 1st script i wrote inside the head tag..
2nd and 3rd script i wrote inside the specified div tag
and finally i called the fuction above the end of body tag.. am i did anything wrong in placing the code..??

Comment: that means it wasn't able to find the div earlier in `destDiv =` line. Does the div exist?  It won't if the DOM hasn't been loaded. You can use the window's "load" event, or just use jQuery-- which provides nicer wrappers for all this.

Comment: You can just put them all at the bottom of the page until you get them working. This will guarantee that all the DOM is loaded. You should just need the two lines `makeCallback... ; setupRssFeed` three times, but the other code should be sharable.

Comment: can any 1 plz... sort out for me.. yet i couldnt..:(

Answer (score 0):

Each div could store the feed URL in it's "id" attribute. Also give them all a class. Finally, include jQuery. Now your code can be something like:

```
<div class='feed' id='http://handheld.softpedia.com/backend-software.xml'></div>
<div class='feed' id='http://handheld.softpedia.com/frontend-software.xml'></div>
```

Then use jQuery to start all the feeds:

```
$('.feed').each(rssfeedsetup1);
```

Just make sure to use the "this" keyword to get the url of the feed (which you get by using this.id) and to append the feed data to it ($(this).append(result))

Comment: can u please edit my code and explain..?? am not clear with ur answer... please help..?? thanks..